# How to capture close event while running a jar file using bat

Tags: batch-file, cmd, jar

I have made a bat file to run a jar file. Whenever a user closes cmd using the close button, I want event should be logged. How do I capture this?

Comment: Do you want to actually show the cmd prompt? It sounds like you'd rather just run the JAR directly.

Comment: Yes cmd will be there as i need to run jar using bat only. just need to know that jar file is successfully closed or someone has closed the cmd @BoffinbraiN

Comment: Can you show us what your batch file looks like so far, and how it behaves? Usually running something from a batch file without `run` will run it synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way I can think to do this is to run a monitor script:

```
@start /WAIT cmd.exe batch.cmd args
@rem Do whatever logging needs to happen here.
```

Depending on how you start the monitor, you can arrange to hide that from the user so they can't kill it.  Take a look at `start /?` for the range of options you can use.